# Populating Meta Tags before DOM is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So this is a weird one - but one I have to resolve.

I am populating meta tags based on whether a form is present or not. I used the form ID in a .ready() function because the jQuery comes before it (in the head) in the DOM.

This is an analytics script and the script's event is in the footer. The script is firing before the tags are populated and no data is being sent. Unfortunately, I cannot modify this script.

Is it possible to pause the DOM loading on the .ready() event of the form?

```
var wtURL = window.location.pathname;
var wtURLParse = wtURL.split('/');
var appType = '1';

if (wtURLParse[3] == 'app') {
    var appType = '2';
}
else {
    var appType = '1'
}


document.write('<META name="placeholder">');


$('#createUsername').ready(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault;
    var isForm = $('#createUsername').length;
console.log(isForm);

    if ( $('#createUsername').length == 1 ) {
        $('META[name="placeholder"]').after('<META NAME="junk" CONTENT="'+ appType +' stuff">\n<META NAME="junk2" CONTENT="stuff2">');
        $('META[name="placeholder"]').remove();
    }
    else {
        if ( $('#createUsername').length == 0 ) {
            $('META[name="placeholder"]').after('<META NAME="junk" CONTENT="'+ appType +' stuff">\n<META NAME="junk2" CONTENT="stuff2">\n<META NAME="junk3" CONTENT="stuff3">');
            $('META[name="placeholder"]').remove();
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a bad idea.

`<meta>` tags are intended to go in the head of the document. The JavaScript would have to be synchronously executed in the head of the document in order to `document.write` the tags in place correctly. This synchronous execution blocks the rendering of the page and is terrible for performance.

[Meta tags - Google Webmaster Tools Help](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=79812)